# How to use onClick in android map to listen for clicks in message window in Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to click marker and show snippet then I click snippet to another window.
Please provide examples and explain the code. Or another way to help advise me.

I want to create application maps. When I click pin on the map, click the snippet I want to show up new layout.

Comment: provide more details please

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, YourActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

This will create another activity then you click in the the info window (the snippet)

Comment: @midtonight You are welcome! If you think this solves our problem and help the community, please accept as the correct answer, so other developers can see that this solution can solve the problem presented in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener`. Take a look at the example below

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            // your code here
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```